# Edit mask on full screen

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to cut out image. I did layer mask, but I would like to be sure that mask is correct (check edges and see if there any whits instead in wrong places).

[image]

For this reason I would like to see mask on full screen. How to do that?

Second option is to see mask on the top of picture instead of "empty" backround:

[image]

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+click (<kbd>Option</kbd>+click on Mac) on the layer mask thumbnail in the layers panel.

Repeat to toggle it back to not visible.

Comment: Helped! Just trying to understand what this operation means. Get I get it somehow from menu or only way is alt+click?

Comment: There is no menu option for this,  but what it actually does is to enable the layer mask channel - essentially selecting the current channel only, while deselecting the other colour channels.